# Create a test report using json as data parameter using java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working on selenium tool and trying to create a html reports of my own using json as a data source to create a simple and neat report.

I understand that there are extend and allure testng and other reports already available, but I want to try and learn to create a report own.

I will be using json java library to create json object which will result like below

```
{
"Tc01" :{
 "Chrome" :[
    {
        "Expected" :"Button should be clicked, 
        "Actual" :Button clicked", 
        "Status" :"Pass" 
    } 
 ] 
} 
}
```

I want this json object to be represented as a test report table.

Please pass me your suggestions thanks in advance

Comment: not sure JSON is necessary unless you are creating a sort of view API that takes it as a parameter.   Otherwise just create the HTML/table in Java.  You can view my HTML report methods here (from my hobby project): https://github.com/pcalkins/browsermator/blob/master/src/browsermator/com/BrowserMatorReport.java

Comment: Hi, can u please post sample report file in this chat or in github

Comment: You can just download from here, run a test (there's some samples in the browsermator cloud) and check the box to output report: 
 https://www.browsermator.com/